# Handle error when rendering string in Python

Tags: python, string, render

I am getting stuck in handling error when rendering string in Python.
I will give the example for clarity.
I have a template string as follow in Python:

```
template = "%(name)s, %(address)s, %(school)s"
```

And I have a dictionary as follow:

```
arg = {'name': nameString,
       'address': addressString,
       }
```

When rendering string using:

```
myFinalStr = template%arg
```

It comes to an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'school'
```

This is because the field "school" could not be found in the template string. How could I handle this error (I cannot use try exception to handle because it is not an exception, I think)

I have to handle this error because I allow the user to input the template, which can be right or wrong.

Comment: "because it is not an exception", it is an exception. It is a [KeyError](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.KeyError)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `try...except`

the basic format would be

```
try:
   myFinalStr = template%arg
except KeyError:
   #do somthing to handle the keyerror
```

or like

```
try:
    template = "%(name)s, %(address)s, %(school)s"
    myFinalStr = template%arg
except KeyError:
     template = "%(name)s, %(address)s"
     myFinalStr = template%arg
```

which will take care of the error.